# Java - OpenFeign - Parse datas from JSON to POJO?

Tags: java, spring, rest, cloud, microservices

I'm having a problem, I want to create a program for extracting from an API data just to print them in console - this via Feign Client from Spring cloud. I'm facing from my Client's class a NullPointerException, but I'm not sure if I understand the issue...

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.List;

@FeignClient(url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
public interface UserServiceClient {

    @GetMapping("/users")
    List<User> getUsersList();
}
```

Is the method List getUsersList(); returning from external API, JSON so, String's items or is the mapping to my model User processed automatically (I'm pretty sure that not :( )?

Many thanks for any help, in my opinion this NullPointer is coming from the fact that the Client is giving me datas on Strings and not POJO, so he is not able to recognize.. But I'm not sure.

Here is the mistake I face:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at UserService.print(UserService.java:14)
    at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:11)
```

Launcher:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Launcher {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      UserService userService = new UserService();
      userService.print();
    }


}
```

UserService:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceClient userServiceClient;


    void print() {

        for (User user : userServiceClient.getUsersList()) {
            System.out.println(
                    "User ID : " + user.getId() + " The name of the user : " + user.getName()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and the UserServiceClient

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.List;

@FeignClient(url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
public interface UserServiceClient {

    @GetMapping("/users")
    List<User> getUsersList();
}
```

Regards,
Erick

Comment: Rather than expressing an _opinion_, include the _stack trace_ that indicates exactly where the NPE occurs.

Comment: I'll edit this :)